# Android Studio not creating working default programs

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a blank activity for a homework assignment, and after I selected Blank Activity and tried to run it on the tablet I'm using, it spits out a ton of errors that I can't make sense of and doesn't run.

[Here's a picture of the error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vV4a.png)

I haven't changed a thing about the program, so I don't know what could be wrong with it. I'm relatively new to Android Studio as well, so I don't know how to begin to fix this.

Comment: your error image say that you try change windowfeature after set content view . you should move that code before setcontentview() in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Error tells that not to call `setContentView()` before calling to `requestFeature()` function

so it would be like this

```
@overide
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
```

Since that you haven't provide your code, Android version that you are working.. this is only a some sort of example compare this with your code
hope this will help you!!

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/COnLv6u) is all the code that is present in the `onCreate()` method directly after the project was opened, so I'm not sure that what you've suggested is what's going wrong here.

Comment: what do you have on line 18 in FaceMaker.java file
can you put the code.. so it will easy to figureout the problem

Comment: The `onCreate()` method contains line 18. Specifically, line 18 is the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_maker);` I included a picture in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't see any fault in that code. Even I created a new project, which works perfectly.. If it is possible edit your question with the full code of FaceMaker.java file

Comment: Oddly enough, I went back and tried running it again, and it worked. Thanks for looking at my code.

Comment: next time please check more deeply before you post... welcome